# prevent some user from viewing some pages

Tags: symfony, permissions

I have a login form and after login I display some links:
I want to prevent non-admin users to click or forward to a specific page.
I don't want to use the symfony2 ROLES cause it is too complicated.
Is there something easier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how do you make the difference between admin and non-admin users in your `User` entity. If it's only a boolean flag (let's say `admin` attribute) :

**User.php**

```
private $admin;
// your attributes

public function isAdmin() 
{ 
     return $this->admin;
}

public function setAdmin($boolean)
{
     $this->admin = $boolean;
}
// getters/setters
```

**FooController.php**

```
public function showAdminPanelAction()
{
  if(!$this->getUser()->isAdmin()) {
       throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Forbidden Access');
  }
  else 
  {
      // do your stuff
  }
}
```

**BUT** Symfony2 roles are making things easier if you have more than 2 two different roles, a hierarchy, lots of users, etc...

Comment: I thought already about the same alternative, but your seems to be better :) thx

Comment: i got this : Fatal error: Call to a member function isAdmin() on a non-object in !!!!

Comment: try var_dump() on $this->getUser() ? How do you manage users ?

Comment: how can I do this ? i didnt use dump befor. and what do you mean by how do I manage users ?

Comment: Do you use FOSUserBundle ? Do you use your own UserInterface implementation ? How do users log in to your application ?

Comment: No I dont use FOSbundle

Comment: $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); how about this one ?

Comment: same : Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55249/discussion-between-kanalkyte-and-bourax-webmaster).